# android psd library to work with psd format

Tags: android, export, psd

I'm looking for a component/library that allows to read a psd and export to a psd in an android app.

[I found a java-psd-library.](http://code.google.com/p/java-psd-library/wiki/PsdFileFormat)

So far I'm successful in reading the psd - detecting layers in the psd. But it seems it cannot export to a psd.

Any direction in this respect would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've never tried to do that but did you try the latest source [from github](https://github.com/inevo/java-psd-library)?

Comment: It doesn't allow exporting to a psd. Also tried http://www.telegraphics.com.au/svn/psdparse/trunk/README.txt   It also doesn't allow creating a psd. Any suggestions?

Comment: One thing I don't get is what do you mean buy "export to a psd"? What do you have in input?

Comment: Consider a drawing mobile app, where a user can import a psd, modify the layers, create new layers and write to a new psd.